# How remove date and time from comments in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I remove date and time from comments in WordPress using add_filter or add_action?

I don't want to use the CSS way.

Comment: you can custom this display with the file `comments.php` of the theme

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the following code in your theme’s functions.php file.

```
// Remove comment date

function wpb_remove_comment_date($date, $d, $comment) { 
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        return;
    } else { 
        return $date;
    }
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'wpb_remove_comment_date', 10, 3);

// Remove comment time
function wpb_remove_comment_time($date, $d, $comment) { 
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
            return;
    } else { 
            return $date;
    }
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_time', 'wpb_remove_comment_time', 10, 3);
```

To remove words like at or posted on right-click to select Inspect from the browser menu.

```
.comment-time { 
display:none; 
}
```

Comment: what is wrong when i get
Call to undefined function add_filter()

Comment: with out requiring or including if you call a function from another function you will get undefined function that means undefined function error happens when you call a function but that function doesn't exists.

It will be easy to help you if you share the code.

Comment: I added the following code in functions.php file.
In functions.php file is 
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/option.php' ); 
on my second site I did the same and there is no problem with Call to undefined function add_filter().

In the file wp-includes/plugin.php function add_filter exist
but functions.php cannot see it